# Scalar subqueries produced more than one element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know this error has been produced many time and a lot of answers came by but I believe every situation might be unique.

So i am trying to get a deficit value(imports - exports) from a table. Both values are on one column

```
value account
100  export
200  import
```

SO now i need to calculate the deficit or surplus, which is either import-export or export-import. I tried scalar subqueries but i am always getting this error.

```
SELECT label, product_type,status,((select value from Task2.quarterly_report where account="Imports") - (select value from Task2.quarterly_report where account="Exports")) As trade_deficit
```

so basically i am trying to get a table with:-

```
label  product_type status trade_deficit
```

Can anyone explain to me the issue and why is it happening and how to solve it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: We'd need to take a look at a few rows of your tables. Most likely `select value from Task2.quarterly_report where account="Imports"` should be something like `select sum(value) from Task2.quarterly_report where account="Imports" and product = trade_deficit.product_type`

Comment: Where "label, product_type,status" are coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when account = 'import' then value
                when account = 'export' then - value
           end)
from t;
```

This is based on the question and sample data.  I don't see what your query has to do with the rest of the question.